# I want to update two seperate mysql databases which are not on the same network

Tags: mysql, database

Okay so I have two MySQL database hosts, when the first one is updated, I want the second database host to be updated aswell.

Query Sending Server (Server 1) -> Database 1 (Server 1) > Database 2 (Server 2)

So the second database I want to update is not on the same machine or not even on the same network with my first database.

In other words, I want to have a backup database which is recieving the queries that the first database has received, but only when they come from the first database.

These two databases are not on the same server.

What I have:

I have phpmyadmin access on Server 1.
Server 2 is a web server.